# Select link based on partial href

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Is there a selector in jQuery that will allow me to select all anchor tags that have a `href` beginning with `href="/products/index?page="`?

My full href is `href="/products/index?page=2"`, but they all have the beginning in common.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the [starts-with attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("a[href^='/products/index?page=']")
```

In case you're curious, there are [other attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) available as well.

Answer (score 4):

[Attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("a[href^='/products/index?page=']")
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the jquery [starts with psuedo selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('[href^=/products/index?page=]')
```